# why does this inequality not hold for all omega

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am not too sure why this inequality does not hold for all omega?

$  -4p^{2} sin^{2}(\frac{\omega}{2}) \geq 0 $  ?

I know sine is bounded between -1 and 1

Comment: LHS is always   positive

Comment: $-x^2\geq0$ for $x=0$ only.

Comment: Somehow, it depends on $p$. Since $sin(x)$ is bounded as you said, you know that $4\sin^2(\omega/2)≥0$ for all $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, if $p$ is real then you are in the case considered by @MichaelRozenberg, if instead $p$ is a pure imaginary complex number then $-4p^2\sin^2(\omega/2)≥0$ for all $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$.